# Loss of special characters while using javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xslt, encoding

I have following problem - I lose some of special characters when using javax.xml.transform.Transformer. Both xml and xls files are UTF-8 formatted.

I seem to lose some of capital polish characters - Ą,Ł etc during transform and replaced by "�?" characters.

Here is my transforming method:

```
public static boolean transform(Logger logger, String inXML,String inXSL,String outTXT)  throws Exception
{  
    try
    {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        ErrorListener listener = new ErrorListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void warning(TransformerException exception)
                    throws TransformerException {}
            @Override
            public void fatalError(TransformerException exception)
                    throws TransformerException {}
            @Override
            public void error(TransformerException exception)
                    throws TransformerException {}
        };
        factory.setErrorListener(listener);
        StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inXSL);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
        StreamSource in = new StreamSource(inXML); 
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outTXT);
        transformer.transform(in,out);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.log("ERROR DURING XSLT TRANSFORM (" + e.getMessage() + ")",2);
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

=====

Using XSL file - [Link](http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/UPO/2008/05/09/UPO.xsl)

Comment: Please show a minimal input document, minimal XSLT code as well as the result you want and the one you get. You might also want to tell us which Java version you use and check which class is created with `factory.newTransformer` in your environment.

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Z1 does not show any loss with Xalan 2.7.1

Comment: I will try to prepare small test case. Could it be a problem with environment character encoding?

Comment: Show us at least the `xsl:output` directive of your XSLT code and then tell us how you look at the created result document.

Comment: XSL file that I use is public. I will attach it to a question.

Comment: So your XSLT creates UTF-8 encoded HTML. How do you look at the HTML? With a browser? Check the encoding the browser uses to render the HTML. Or do you use a text editor that simply uses your system's default code page or encoding which may be an 8-bit code page and not UTF-8?

Comment: That's right. My browser uses UTF-8 encoding for sure. When i use text editor (Notepad+ with UTF-8 encoding) however i got artifacts like:  "OSTROxC5?xC4?KA" instead of OSTROŁĘKA. 

I tested it on another JRE and I got this problem only when using Java 1.6. (IBM Notes Java). When using standard 1.7 jdk in Eclipse on the same files it works fine.

I don't know if it is environment or java problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with IBM Notes Java, I don't know whether there is a tag for it, hopefully someone else can help. Or perhaps you can try putting a different XSLT processor like Saxon 9 (don't know whether it works with Java 1.6) or Saxon 6.5.5 or the latest version of Xalan on the class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed it was necessary to set output encoding.
After adding

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

engine seems to work fine in both environments.

Answer (score -1):

I had similiar problem and after adding UTF-16 (not UTF-8) encoding

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-16");
```

special characters worked.